# What does this C expression mean?

Tags: c, expression

Looking for some code to reuse in my C app I came across this expression:

```
MDO = ((output_data & 0x80) ? 1 : 0);
```

I understand what is between brackets but what does `? 1 : 0`  mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is shorthand for `if-else`, called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a).

In your case it is equal to:

```
if (output_data & 0x80) {
   MDO = 1;
} else {
   MDO = 0;
}
```

And a little word of advice, don't use it for complicated `if` constructs, it hinders readability. Only use it in cases like this, where it can be understood immediately.

Answer (score 3):

'?' is the ternary operator, it's a short-hand for

```
if ((output_data & 0x80) != 0) { MDO = 1; } else { MDO = 0; }
```

which will assign `1` to MDO if output_data has bit 8 set (0x80 = 128 = bit 8), otherwise MDO gets the value of `0`

A simpler example: There are 10 beers on Friday, otherwise there's only 2.

```
int beers = (day == Friday) ? 10 : 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

it means if the expression is true than MDO will have the value of 1 else 0

Answer (score 1):

output_data& 0x80 is a bitwise binary and. So it returns 0x80 if that particualr bit is on out_putdata otherwise it returns 0

MDO=    ?  :

Is the same as

```
if (expression)
    MDO = 1    
else
    MDO = 0
```

so MDO will be 1 if the bit is on on output_data otherwise it is 0

Comment: It is not the same. The ternary operator will not `return`.

Comment: I mean return the expression no 'return' from the function.. fixing to make clearer